# Parsing JSON with Decodable

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

I am having a hard time figuring out how to combine similar json results so that while searching the API, the search results only display a particular medication name once.  I am running into the same problem for the strength as well.  When the medication is selected, multiple rows are filled with the same strength due to the medications having different package codes (which need to be used to determine drug package coverage).  Any ideas? I am not sure if I should be parsing it a different way.

Here is an example of the JSON in a playground:

```
let json = """
{
"meta": {
  "total": 406
},
"drugs": [
{
   "id": "12547-0204",
   "active_ingredient_strength": "10mg",
   "proprietary_name": "Zyrtec",
   "non_proprietary_name": "Zyrtec"
   "drug_package_ids": [
    "12547-0204-30",
    "12547-0204-32",
    "12547-0204-36"
  ]
   },

{
   "id": "52959-0482",
   "active_ingredient_strength": "10mg",
   "proprietary_name": "Zyrtec",
   "non_proprietary_name": "Zyrtec"
   "drug_package_ids": [
    "52959-0482-01",
    "52959-0482-07",
    "52959-0482-10",
    "52959-0482-15",
    "52959-0482-30"
  ]
   },
{ 
   "id": "54868-5879",
   "active_ingredient_strength": "5; 120mg/1; mg/1",
   "proprietary_name": "ZYRTEC",
   "non_proprietary_name": "Cetirizine Hydrochloride and Pseudoephedrine      
   Hydrochloride",
   "drug_package_ids": [
    "54868-5879-0",
    "54868-5879-00",
    "54868-5879-00"
     ]
   }
  ]
}""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct DrugSearchResponse: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let drugs: [Drugs]

    struct Meta: Codable {
        let total: Int
    }
    struct Drugs: Codable {
        let id: String
        let active_ingredient_strength: String
        let proprietary_name: String
        let non_proprietary_name: String
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let results = try! decoder.decode(DrugSearchResponse.self, from: json)
let drugs = results.drugs
for name in drugs {
    print(name.proprietary_name)
}
```

---

Here is a screen shot of the search results for reference:

- [Search Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S1FA.png)
- [StrengthViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvARS.png)

Comment: A possible solution would be to remove dupes from the array by using filter or Dictionary's grouping initializer

Comment: You are presupposing that Decoder is capable of or responsible for removing duplicates.  It's not, that's your responsibility.  All that the Decoder is responsible for is turning valid JSON into a valid swift object.  Removing duplicates is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the contents of your custom array and remove duplicate valued items based on any property.

e.g. this removes all drugs with the same proprietary name except the first one

```
let result: [Drugs] = []
result.append(contentsOf: results.drugs.filter { item in
    !result.contains(where: { $0.proprietary_name == item.proprietary_name })
})
```